# Apply lambda function to numpy array elementwise doesnt work

Tags: python, numpy

I am not quite sure why this isn´t working.. any explanation is highly appreciated.
Mapping a function to np.array like:

```
test = np.array([0.6,0.7,1,0,0.5,0.2,0.4,0.3])
decision_boundary=0.6
decision_func = lambda x: 1. if (x >= decision_boundary) else 0.
decision_func(test)
```

results in the following value-error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: just `(test>=decision_boundary).astype(float)`.

Comment: result = test>=decision_boundary will give you a boolean numpy array. result2=result.astype(np.int8) should switch it to 1s and 0s.

Comment: I was rather curious why it doesnt work, but thanks for the suggestions anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not applying the function to each element of the array. You're applying the function to the whole array, and numpy is rightly telling you you can't convert a numpy array to Boolean to be used as the condition of `if`. Fortunately, in your case, `>=` is already vectorized on numpy arrays, so you can just do

```
x >= decision_boundary
```

Or if you really want ones and zeroes,

```
1 * (x >= decision_boundary)
```

In general, if you have a function that's not vectorized, you can make it so with the numpy function [`vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html).